# Two-way repeated measures ANOVA python function

Tags: python, statistics

Thanks in advance for any answers. I want to conduct a 2-way repeated measures ANOVA in python where one IV has 5 levels and the other 4 levels, with one DV. I've tried looking around in scipy documentation and a few online blogs but can't seem to find anything.

Comment: So far as I know, mixed-effects and hierarchical models haven't been fully implemented in scipy. There's a mixed-effects sandbox module that's not finished, but I don't know how accurate the results are. If you want, you can look into PyStan. It requires a bit more coding, but you can analyze whatever model you think up.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

this is an old question but I will provide an answer.

You could take a look at [pyvttbl](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyvttbl). Using this library (can be installed via Pip) you can carry out n-way ANOVA for both independent and repeated measures (and mixed designs). Note that it seems like that you will have to use Pyvttbl own data frame method to handle your data.

It is pretty simple:

```
dataframe.anova('dv', sub='id', wfactors=['iv1',      'iv2'])
```

You can see my blog post for a more elaborated example on how to carry out a [2-way ANOVA for repeated measures](http://www.marsja.se/two-way-anova-repeated-measures-using-python/).

Answer (score 8):

You can use the [rm_anova](https://pingouin-stats.org/generated/pingouin.rm_anova.html) function in the Pingouin package (of which I am the creator) that works directly with pandas DataFrame, e.g.:

```
import pingouin as pg

# Compute the 2-way repeated measures ANOVA. This will return a dataframe.
pg.rm_anova(dv='dv', within=['iv1', 'iv2'], subject='id', data=df)

# Optional post-hoc tests
pg.pairwise_ttests(dv='dv', within=['iv1', 'iv2'], subject='id', data=df)
```

Comment: How do I check whether the assumptions such as sphericity and normality are met? I see that methods have only been implemented for one-way repeated measures ANOVA.